# Река Миасс

Tags: топонимика

Давно интересует происхождение названия реки Миасс. Слово напоминает какую-то аббревиатуру советских времен)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это очень древний топоним. Вообще известно, что гидронимы обычно сохряняют своё название от первых народов, живших в тех местах.

По наиболее популярной версии в русский язык попало из башкирского, однако и в нем является заимствованием от более раннего населения, финоугорского. Сравнительным анализом ряда топонимов можно предположить, что формант "ас" или "аш" имеет значение "вода".